# eliminar string de un array javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array con estos elemetos

```
soloNumeros([1, 'pepe', 2])
```

lo que quiero lograr es eliminar los strings de mi array
mi codigo

```
function soloNumeros(array) {

var recorrido = array;
var string_array = "";
for (let i = 0; i < recorrido.length; i++) {
  if (recorrido === string_array){
    recorrido.splice(i,1);
  }
 }
return recorrido;
 }
```

Comment: Al hacer `recorrido = array` no estás copiando el contenido de la variable `array` en la variable `recorrido`, solo estás copiando la referencia a la posición en memoria. Lo que modifiques en una, se verá reflejado en la otra.

Comment: @BetaM solucionado

Answer (score 1):

Dado que solo quieres elementos que no sean string...

```
function soloNumeros(array) {
    return Array.isArray(array) ? array.filter(i => typeof i !== "string") : [];
}
```

typeof devolverá el tipo de elemento, y filter devolverá solo los elementos que coincidan con la condición, todos los que no sean string.

Array.isArray es solo para corroborar estar enviando datos completos. Filter no es una función que funcione fuera de un array.

Answer (score 0):

Perfecto!
lo hice distinto, pero llegue

```js
function soloNumeros (array) {

    return array.filter (numero => typeof numero !== "string")
    }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).